# Azure Service Management API metadata

Tags: azure, wsdl

I'm trying to locate metadata (preferably a WSDL spec) for the APIs described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460799.aspx. IIUC, WCF services (which I presume was used to implement these REST services) nearly automatically provide their metadata. If so: how to access such a description? If not: is a WSDL spec for them available elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think WSDL is available for the Windows Azure Service Management API, sorry.